# Linking files as headers in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to include other c++ files I have worked on to be included as headers in my main. I am simply dragging the files into my Xcode project by clicking and dragging. I keep getting this message

error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

This is so annoying because I know my code works when I run it through terminal because I made a manual makefile for my program. Does Xcode also need a makefile to run the executable?  How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to read the entire error message (or possibly even command line command that Xcode generates) to see which file is causing you the problem. Are the c++ files .cpp or .h files?

Comment: Ok. The files are both .cpp and .h